# Page slider in website

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am new to web programming. I want to build something like [flip.hr](http://flip.hr/). What interested me was the sliding effect created when we click on the navigation bar in the bottom of the page.
What I currently know is [this](http://www.coffeecup.com/help/articles/how-do-i-link-to-different-sections-on-the-same-page-html-editor/), where you create hyperlinks to different portions of the page and on clicking at them your are taken to a particular portion. Now I want to create sliding effect as done [here](http://flip.hr/). Please guide me to achieve this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[**LIVE DEMO**](http://jsbin.com/hifod/1/)

It's terribly simple,
let's say you have a bottom navigation and an `#pages DIV` that will have as first children the desired `DIV` pages:

```
<div id="pages">  
  <div id="home">HOME PAGE</div>
  <div id="about">ABOUT PAGE</div>
  <div id="products">PRODUCTS PAGE</div>
  <div id="contact">CONTACT</div> 
</div>

<table id="nav">
  <tr>
    <td><a href="#home">HOME</a></td>
    <td><a href="#about">ABOUT</a></td>
    <td><a href="#products">PRODUCTS</a></td>
    <td><a href="#contact">CONTACT</a></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

all you need is to `position:fixed` the `#nav` at the bottom and set `absolute` as `width` and `height` **100%** your pages:

```
#pages > div{
  position:absolute;
  width:100%;
  height:100%;
}
#pages div + div{ // To keep "HOME page" at 0 but push away all other pages
    left:-100%; /* note this */
}

// Style buttons and pages
#home,    a[href="#home"]    {background:#078;}
#about,   a[href="#about"]   {background:#780;}
#products,a[href="#products"]{background:#807;}
#contact, a[href="#contact"] {background:#088;}

#nav{
  position:fixed;
  bottom:0;
  width:100%;
  table-layout:fixed;
}
#nav a{
  display:block;
}
```

all you need is this tiny bit of jQuery:

```
jQuery(function($){

    function showPage( pageID ){
      var pID = pageID || window.location.hash;
      $('#pages > div:gt(0)').animate({left: '-100%'}, 600);
      $(pID).stop().animate({left:0}, 600);
    }
    showPage();

    $('#nav a').click(function(){
      showPage( $(this).attr('href') );
    });

});
```

Note how the navigation anchors have the same *anchor name* as the relative pages `ID`.
**Now to explain:**

```
$('#nav a').click(function(){
```

will set by default a `#pagename` hash in the URL bar, now all we need is a function that will read the targeted page ID by the passed argument `pageID` OR (`||`) if there was no argument go read the `window.location.hash` from the addressbar.

Doing that way you make sure that if I cpoy paste a page link to a friend like:

```
http://www.example.com/#contact
```

the `showPage();` function trigger will bring him to the desired page.

Inside the function we make sure to always keep home page at 0 left pixels by simply targeting all other pages using the jQuery `:gt()` selector (*greater than index*):

```
$('#pages > div:gt(0)').animate({left: '-100%'}, 600); // speaks by itself
```

than we simply target the needed page `ID` and we animate it in place.

- Did we passed the clicked anchor `href` attribute,
- Did the loaded page already had an `hash` in the addressbar.

---

With jQuery another way to do it would be also simply like

```
$('#nav a').click(showPage);
```

but than inside our function we should be waiting for the HASH to change before we could apply any animation. For that purpose a `setTimeout would be fine:`

```
function showPage(){
  setTimeout(function(){
    $('#pages > div:gt(0)').animate({left: '-100%'}, 600);
    $(window.location.hash).stop().animate({left:0}, 600);
  },100);
}
showPage();
```

Comment: @unknown you're welcome! I just have to warn you as you're a new user to SOverflow, next time when you'll be asking questions, show some code pointing on a specific issue you encountered, otherwise you might collect downvotes of even see you question closed. Happy coding

Answer (score 1):

You can actually set a page as section and try to do the transform on click event.
This will be really helpful.
[This will help You](http://css3.bradshawenterprises.com/sliding/)

Answer (score 1):

If you are a little bit familiar with jQuery, you can eventually use the [.show()](http://jqueryui.com/show/) function from jQuery UI, using the `slide` effect.

Or, you can make it only with HTML/CSS, there are plenty of tutorials on the web, like [this one](http://mrbool.com/how-to-create-slideshow-with-html5-and-css/27166), but with divs that make 100% width and height.