# make content slide in and out when clicking link?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am green in this area and I am trying to learn while I build a virtual resume for a website I can use to advertise my programming services (my strength lies more with C#, Java and similar languages :')

Something I think would look pretty cool, is if when you click on a link in my side-bar, the content on the page slides out and is replaced with the content on the new page that slides in, in the previous page' place.

I am a bit lost on how to achieve this though and if I have to do a per-page thing, or if I can make one general method in Javascript to take care of it. I am using `jQuery` and `bootstrap`.

```
var main;
main = function () {
    $(".sidebar-nav a").click(function() {
        <!-- Not sure what to do here -->
        <!-- Pseudo Code -->
        <!-- find out what element was pressed
             slide out content on current page using animate();
             slide in content from the element that was pressed using animate(); -->
    })
}

$("document").ready(main);
```

The HTML:

```
<div id="wrapper">

    <!-- Sidebar -->
    <div id="sidebar-wrapper">
        <ul class="sidebar-nav">
            <li class="sidebar-brand">
                <h1>Brand</h1>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="#">
                    Index
                </a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="#">
                    About Me
                </a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="#">
                    Resume
                </a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="#">
                    Contact
                </a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>

    <!-- Content -->
    <div id="page-content-wrapper">
        <div class="container-fluid">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-lg-12">
                    <h1>h1</h1>
                    <h2>h2</h2>
                    <h3>h3</h3>
                    <h4>h4</h4>
                    <h5>h5</h5>
                    <h6>h6</h6>
                    <p>Grumpy wizards make toxic brew for the evil Queen and Jack.</p>
                    <a href="#menu-toggle" class="btn btn-default" id="menu-toggle">Toggle Menu</a>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Let me know if you need the CSS.

Comment: Something similar to [this ?](http://stackoverflow.com/a/21814409/383904)

Comment: comment in js: single line `//`, multiple line `/*some comment*/`

Comment: If you've got the CSS, please provide it.

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan Yes, that looks pretty much like what I'd like.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use an AJAX technology to seamlessly load another page's HTML contents inline into the document.

The best choice (in my opinion) for this situation is the jQuery function [load()](http://api.jquery.com/load/), due to it's simplicity and pure convenience. You can also send a callback function, it's easy to implement.

You could then easily implement a CSS animation using the `animation` attribute.

Comment: Following the link from @RokoC.Buljan have given me the desired effect. Though I will like to accept your answer as it is an alternative solution to what he posted :)

Comment: Thank you! I tell you, AJAX is like magic if you ever try using it! @Vipar